# How to perform touch event on link using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform touch event on a link using javascript.
Having issue while triggering click event.
I have tried to perform click event on that but that's not working at all.
Here is the code of link where i want to click.

```
$('#next_button,#bottom_next_button,#next_arrow,.image_inner_a').on('touchstart',function(e){
    if(e.touches&&e.touches[0].pageX>5){
        this.href=this.href.replace(/[&?]z=[^&]*/,'');valid_user=true;
    }
});
$('#next_button,#bottom_next_button,#next_arrow,.image_inner_a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    next_ajax();
    return false;
});
$('#prev_arrow,#prev_button').click(function(e){
    prev_ajax();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
window.onpopstate=function(event){
    if(pop_state){
    pop_state=0;return;
}
```

I am analyzing this website so I am trying to touch the button through javascript.
I am trying to touch the ID #next_button

Comment: Have you tried `trigger` event ? `$("linkID_or_Class").trigger("click", callback)`

Comment: Touch works by default in the latest Jquery versions.. Why do you need to trigger events?

Comment: If its one of those older versions which does not support touch then you may look up touchpunch.js which enables touch events directly as you write click..

Comment: nope! i am trying just to perform touch on the website via debug console chrome.

Comment: @SandeepNayak Didn't worked. I just want  touch on #next_button using javascript. I am not trying to capture touch event the code posted above is to tell where i am trying to click.